# Running a bash command as root in WSL2 from an elevated command prompt?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run the command below, from an elevated cmd I get the following error and as far as I can tell it's because of the less than symbol; or maybe it's because it won't let you access the Linux file system from Windows (even though I know there's a Linux file system hidden in the Windows system / User profile somewhere.

```
C:\>wsl -u root cat < /root/projects/steakandcleese/620_login_mofo.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So do I need to be escaping the less than symbol or try to find the linux path that would be buried somewhere in `/mnt/c/`?

Comment: As written, it's the Windows shell that's trying to process the input redirection; try `wsl -u root cat /root/projects/steakandcleese/620_login_mofo.txt` instead so that the file name is passed as an argument to the wsl command

Comment: @steeldriver That is not my actual command.  The actual command I'm running for some reason requires a `<` instead of a `|`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where `|` comes from - however you could always do something like `wsl -u root sh -c "cat < /root/projects/steakandcleese/620_login_mofo.txt"` if you need to run commands in a shell

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you sir!